# Simplificar o uso de vários replaces all

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho o seguinte

```
var res;
$(window).load(function(){
  $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
     res = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);
     res = res.replace(/:/g, '');
     res = res.replace(/\"/g, '');
     res = res.replace(/\n/g, '');
     res = res.replace("{", "");  
     res = res.replace("}", ""); 
     res = res.replace("ip", ""); 
     res = res.replace("hostname", "");
     res = res.replace("city", "");
     res = res.replace("region", "");
     res = res.replace("country", "");
     res = res.replace("loc", "");
     res = res.replace("org", "");
     res = res.replace(/ /g, '');

     $("#dados").html("Dados: " + res); 

   }, "jsonp");

});
```

> res = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4); antes de aplicar os vários replaces retorna

```
{
"ip": "187.155.67.279",
"hostname": "b1c33eb3.virtua.com.br",
"city": "Leblon",
"region": "Rio de Janeiro",
"country": "BR",
"loc": "-22.8244,-43.0353",
"org": "AS28573 CLARO S.A."
}
```

> E depois dos catataus de replaces retorna

```
187.155.67.279,b1c33eb3.virtua.com.br,Leblon,Rio de Janeiro,BR,-22.8244,-43.0353,AS28573 CLARO S.A.
```

Então a pergunta é: Como evitar esse montão de replaces, e atribuir o resultado na variável **res**

Comment: É uma json, talvez seja mais simples fazer o parse e iterar os elementos e jogar em uma string.

Comment: sim,mas como se faz isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando o texto:

```
const value = `{
  "ip": "187.155.67.279",
  "hostname": "b1c33eb3.virtua.com.br",
  "city": "Leblon",
  "region": "Rio de Janeiro",
  "country": "BR",
  "loc": "-22.8244,-43.0353",
  "org": "AS28573 CLARO S.A."
}`;
```

Você pode fazer:

```
var result = Object.values(JSON.parse(value)).join();
```

O resultado de `console.log(result)` é:

```
187.155.67.279,b1c33eb3.virtua.com.br,Leblon,Rio de Janeiro,BR,-22.8244,-43.0353,AS28573 CLARO S.A.
```

**Funcionamento**

Basicamente fazemos a análise do JSON através de `JSON.parse`, criando um objeto do JavaScript. Com `Object.values` obtemos a lista dos valores dos atributos do objeto e, finalmente, com `join` unimos todos os valores em uma única *string*.

```js
const value = `{
    "ip": "187.155.67.279",
    "hostname": "b1c33eb3.virtua.com.br",
    "city": "Leblon",
    "region": "Rio de Janeiro",
    "country": "BR",
    "loc": "-22.8244,-43.0353",
    "org": "AS28573 CLARO S.A."
}`;

var result = Object.values(JSON.parse(value)).join();

console.log(result);
```

**Exemplo**

Um trecho de código que talvez se aproxime mais à sua aplicação. Neste caso, o valor de `response` já foi analisado como JSON e, portanto, não necessita utilizar `JSON.parse`, o mesmo já é um objeto JavaScript.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  
     let res = Object.values(response).join();
     
     $("#dados").html("Dados: " + res); 
     
  }, "jsonp");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dados"></div>
```

Comment: desculpe o trabalho, não consegui aplicar, refiz a pergunta.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo qual foi o problema?

Comment: não consegui jogar o resultado dentro da variavel ver

Comment: Como não? A variável `result` do exemplo já retorna esse valor certinho.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Adicionei ao final da resposta um **exemplo**, veja se não é algo assim que desejas.

Comment: Que maravilha, simplificou mais do que eu pedi, parabéns, economizei vários linhas, o código foi resumido a 6 linhas.  Só mais uma pergunta -  é necessário declarar a variável res?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não, poderia ser utilizado diretamente: `$("#dados").html("Dados: " + Object.values(response).join()); `

Answer (score 3):

Você pode transforma a string em um objeto usando o `JSON.parse`, então pode pegar todas as chaves do objeto usando o método `Object.key()`, por fim basta percorrer as chaves com um `forEach`.

No caso abaixo, usei o `map` ao invés do `forEach`, pois queria mapear os valores para um novo array.

```js
var json = '{ \
  "ip": "187.155.67.279", \
  "hostname": "b1c33eb3.virtua.com.br", \
  "city": "Leblon", \
  "region": "Rio de Janeiro", \
  "country": "BR", \
  "loc": "-22.8244,-43.0353", \
  "org": "AS28573 CLARO S.A." \
}';

var _obj = JSON.parse(json);
var keys = Object.keys(_obj);
var values = keys.map(function (key, indice) {
  console.log(key + ": " + _obj[key]);
  return _obj[key];
});
console.log(values);
```

**EDIT**

Você já recebe um objeto, então não há a necessidade de fazer um parse.

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    res = Object.keys(response).map(function (key) {
        return response[key];
    }).join();
    $("#dados").html("Dados: " + res);
}, "jsonp");
```

veja funcionando.:

```js
var json = '{ \
  "ip": "187.155.67.279", \
  "hostname": "b1c33eb3.virtua.com.br", \
  "city": "Leblon", \
  "region": "Rio de Janeiro", \
  "country": "BR", \
  "loc": "-22.8244,-43.0353", \
  "org": "AS28573 CLARO S.A." \
}';

var response = JSON.parse(json);
var res = Object.keys(response).map(function (key, indice) {
  return response[key];
}).join();

console.log(res);

// usando o reduce (elimina a necessidade do join, mas o codigo fica menos legivel).
res = Object.keys(response).reduce(function (keyA, keyB) {
  return (response[keyA] || keyA) + "," + response[keyB];
});

console.log(res);
```

**P.S.:** evite usar o `Object.values()`, ele ainda é experimental e não é suportado pela maioria dos Browsers.

Comment: desculpe o trabalho, não consegui jogar o resultado dentro da variavel ver

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo editei a resposta.

Comment: mas a var json seria a minha primeira var res? res = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);

Comment: com a idéia de replace, regex, function na cabeça, deixei escapar a solução mais simples que ora me ocorreu, dentro do contexto da pergunta editada a solução é::  res = (response.ip + "," + response.hostname+ "," + response.city+ "," + response.region+ "," + response.country+ "," + response.loc+ "," + response.org);

Comment: @TobiasMesquita bem observado quando ao `Object.values`. Quanto a sua solução, possivelmente ficaria mais idiomática utilizando o `reduce`, no lugar do `map`, não acha? Algo [assim](https://repl.it/HQ8w/0).

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo esta não é uma boa solução quando está tratando o retorno de outra aplicação, porque a qualquer momento os nomes poderão ser alterados e seu código passará a dar erro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu particularmente não gosto de abusar do reduce, para quem não o conhece, ele é meio confuso, atualizei o exemplo para usar ele, veja como não fica legal.

Comment: gostei da dica " a qualquer momento os nomes poderão ser alterados...."